# log4j2 with custom argument like logback ClassicConverter

Tags: log4j2

I am working on some logging in log4j2, as one of the arguments I pass in pojo. I would like to intercept this and create a custom string from the pojo. The pojo is a collection of keyValue pairs. I have implemented this in logback using ClassicConverter. I have debugged but it doesn't look like I have access to the argArray

LOGGER.info("custom data in log {}", eventFields);

Is this doable in log4j2 converter or maybe I need to use a diff type of plugin.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Wrap your collection in a MapMessage and log the message. If using the PatternLayout you can then use %K to select what you want.
2. Same as item one but implement a custom PatternConverter to format the Map.
3. Extend MapMessage and override one of the formatting methods.
4. Implement a custom pattern converter that can handle the Message types your application is using (see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/messages.html).

From your description it sounds like you are trying to write a custom PatternConverter. I suspect the problem you are having is that the object you are looking for is attached to the Message object in the log event, not in the log event itself. You should be able to get access to it via the Message.getParameters() method.